# I cannot cancel the fullscreen with the method given in FullScreen API

Tags: javascript, html, fullscreen

Here is the error that I am getting in Google Chrome:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'webkitCancelFullScreen'
```

I get a similar error in Firefox.

Here is the code:

```
document.id('close-full-screen').addEvent('click', function() {
    document.id('full-screen').webkitCancelFullScreen();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Documentation found here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Using_full-screen_mode), `webkitCancelFullScreen` is called from the `document` object not a div. Thus, your code should be.

```
document.id('close-full-screen').addEvent('click', function() {
  document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
});
```

Here is an example using [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brantolsen/ejUWt/show/). The correct code can be found [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/73Wus/).